# VS Code "Show Search" View is shown as "Source Control"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I do `"Ctrl + Shift + f"`, the "Show Search" View is displayed but the icon on the Activity Bar show it as Source Control and at the top of the "Show Search" View, the Source Control Repository is being displayed. I have disabled all extensions and look around for a settings that I might messed up but cannot find anything.

Does anyone know how to get the Search icon back for the Show Search View and remove the Source Control repository section from the Search View?

VS Code version is 1.64

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must have the dragged Search into the SCM View.

To reset it, from the Command Palette:

`View: Reset View Locations`

Comment: That's most likely the case. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 0):

simply go to keyboard shortcuts in vscode and search for `search:find in files`

[image]

Then you can easily change your desired shortcut